# build new array which contains several array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I build several array which one contain an object, what I want is to build a new one which contain every object. Here is my code:

```
for(i = 0; i < tabuser.length; i++){
    var urls = [];
    urls.push({
        url: JSON.stringify("https://cubber.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/"+tabuser[i].id+"/tickets/requested.json")
    });
console.log(urls);
```

here is my `console.log(urls)`

[image]

i want something like this:

```
[ 
    { newurl: 'ajax1.html' },
    { newurl: 'ajax2.html' },
    { newurl: 'ajax3.html' }
]
```

Comment: move `var urls = [];` out from loop

Comment: i close the braquet be later so it's normal i didn t show u

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are recreating the array in every loop. Use the following instead:

```
var urls = [];
for(i = 0; i < tabuser.length; i++){
    urls.push({url:JSON.stringify("https://cubber.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/"+tabuser[i].id+"/tickets/requested.json")});
}
console.log(urls);
```

Comment: i accept your answer as soon as possible it was quite simple.. :)

Answer (score 6):

Move the array declaration before `for`. If that is kept inside `for` the variable will be initialised for each iteration of array and previous data in it will be flushed.

```
var urls = []; // <--- Move it here

for(i = 0; i < tabuser.length; i++) {
    urls.push({
        url: JSON.stringify("https://cubber.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/" + tabuser[i].id + "/tickets/requested.json")
    });
}

console.log(urls);
```

---

As an option, you can also use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Also note that there is no need of `JSON.stringify` if the `id` is primitive.

```
var urls = tabuser.map(obj => ({
    url: "https://cubber.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/" + obj.id + "/tickets/requested.json"
}));
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want this:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(urls))
```

What you are seeing in the console is actually the objects being listed, you just need to expand them by clicking on the down arrow beside [Object]

Answer (score 2):

You can easily map the current array to a new array like this:

```
var urls = tabuser.map(function(t){
    return { newurl: "https://cubber.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/"+t.id+"/tickets/requested.json" };
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(urls))
```

Comment: you get array of string, but OP want get array of objects

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid errors like this if would be use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var urls = tabuser.map(function(user){
    return {
        url: JSON.stringify("https://cubber.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/" + user.id + "/tickets/requested.json")
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

rewrite it as

```
    var urls = [];
        for(i = 0; i < tabuser.length; i++)
        {
             urls.push({ 
    url:JSON.stringify("https://cubber.zendesk.com/api/v2/users/"+tabuser[i].id+"/tickets/requested.json")
});
        }
             console.log(urls);
```